# Gigantic memory use in example pytorch program. Why?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have been trying to debug a program using vast amounts of memory and have distilled it into the following example:

```
# Caution, use carefully, this can utilise all available memory on your computer
# and render it effectively unresponsive, to the point where you cannot access
# the shell to kill the process; thus requiring reboot.

import numpy as np
import collections
import torch

# q = collections.deque(maxlen=1500)  # Uses around 6.4GB
# q = collections.deque(maxlen=3000)  # Uses around 12GB
q = collections.deque(maxlen=5000)  # Uses around 18GB

def f():
    nparray = np.zeros([4,84,84], dtype=np.uint8)
    q.append(nparray)
    nparray1 = np.zeros([32,4,84,84], dtype=np.float32)
    tens = torch.tensor(nparray1, dtype=torch.float32)

while True:
    f()
```

Please note the cautionary message in the 1st line of this program. If you set maxlen to a level where it uses too much of your available RAM, it can crash your computer.

I measured the memory using top (VIRT column), and its memory use seems wildly excessive (details on the commented lines above). From previous experience in my original program if maxlen is high enough it will crash my computer.

Why is it using so much memory?

I calculate the increase in expected memory from maxlen=1500 to maxlen=3000 to be:

4 * 84 * 84 * 15000 / (1024**2) == 403MB.

But we see an increase of 6GB.

There seems to be some sort of interaction between using collections and the tensor allocation as commenting either out causes memory use to be expected; eg commenting out the tensor line leads to total memory use of 2GB which seems much more reasonable.

Thanks for any help or insight,

Julian.

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: Python 3.8.5, Pytorch 1.11.0+cu102, Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS

Answer (score -1):

I think PyTorch store and update the computational graph each time you call `f()`, and thus the graph-size just keeps getting bigger and bigger.
Can you try to free the memory usage by using `del(tens)` (deleting the reference for the variable after usage), and let me know how it works? (found in PyTorch-documents here: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/faq.html)

Comment: OK, have added del(tens) as last line of f(), but it makes no difference to memory usage.